# how I can give link to slide to redirect to other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am creating a slide show in with help of Jquery as below.I am  able to get the slide show .But I am not able to give the link to each slide using href

Plseae help me .

```
<body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .fade {
            position: relative;
            width: 650px;
            height: 373px;
        }
        .fade img {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 650px;
            height: 373px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.fade img:gt(0)').hide();
            setInterval(function () { 
                $('.fade :first-child').fadeOut(3000)
                    .next('img').fadeIn(3000).end()
                    .appendTo('.fade'); 
            }, 4000);
        });
    </script>

    <div class="fade" style="width: 603px; height: 373px; z-index: 1; border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; left: 295px; top: 224px; position: absolute">
        <img src="images/SAM_0043.JPG" href="www.xyz.com" >
        <img src="images/SAM_0047.JPG" href="www.xyz.com" >
        <img src="images/SAM_0044.JPG" href="www.xyz.com" >
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<a  href="www.xyz.com"><img src="images/SAM_0043.JPG" ></a>
```

---

`img` tag has no `href` attribute.

wrap `img` tag with `a` tag n give `href`

---

Or with jQuery using your current code wrap `a` tag around `img`

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/ck25X/)</kbd>

```
$('div.fade img').wrap(function () {
    return '<a href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"></a>';
});
```

Comment: this gives link only to the first slide and second slides shows balank screen not giving link

Comment: @FaisalThayyil you have to wrap all images in `a` tag example `<a  href="www.xyz.com"><img src="slide1.JPG" ></a> <a  href="www.xyz.com"><img src="slide2.JPG" ></a><a  href="www.xyz.com"><img src="slide3.JPG" ></a>` or use jQuery see demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/ck25X/

Comment: I have given to all  img .but still not working .only for first slide it is working

Comment: slide link is different for different img.So how to configur JQuery in my code

Comment: @FaisalThayyil it will handle it .You don't worry just use it properly.You know how to use it ?

Answer (score 0):

embed the img tag into the anchor tag, and provide the href="" to the anchor tag. Your work is done.

Answer (score 0):

href is not an img tag attribute so better to change the html to

```
<a href=""><img src="" /></a>
```

and if you dont want to change your html you can use code below to redirect to links on click on images

```
$(".fade img").bind('click',function(){
    window.location = $(this).attr("href");
});
```